# How to update Deployment in Minikube with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, deployment, kubectl, minikube

I like to update my three Deployments on Minikube with Jenkins. So I configured a Shell command in a Jenkins-Job and put this in as command:

```
kubectl set image deployment/dev-lager dev-lager=volkanb/lagertest:latest
kubectl set image deployment/dev-lager dev-lager=volkanb/lagertest

kubectl set image deployment/test-lager test-lager=volkanb/lagertest:latest
kubectl set image deployment/test-lager test-lager=volkanb/lagertest

kubectl set image deployment/prod-lager prod-lager=volkanb/lagertest:latest
kubectl set image deployment/prod-lager prod-lager=volkanb/lagertest
```

When I type these commands manually it works. But configured as Shell commands in a Jenkins-Job it doesn't. What can I do to solve that problem?

Comment: Have you tried other kubectl commands as a Jenkins Job? Is your Jenkins deployed inside kubernetes as well? I'm asking because your jenkins may not have appropriate permissions to modify deployments

Comment: No its not deployed inside Kubernetes. So how do I give permissions to Jenkins on Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run kubernetes jobs from Jenkins you have to configure the credentials for cluster access first.

- One great option is to follow the tutorial in [Kubernetes Plugin Documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes). It has the step-by-step on how to configure the credentials.
- Under section **Kubernetes Cloud Configuration**:

  > In Jenkins settings click on add cloud, select Kubernetes and fill the
  >   information, like Name, Kubernetes URL, Kubernetes server certificate
  >   key, ...
  >
  > If Kubernetes URL is not set, the connection options will be
  >   autoconfigured from service account or kube config file.
  >
  > When running the Jenkins master outside of Kubernetes you will need to
  >   set the credential to secret text. The value of the credential will be
  >   the token of the service account you created for Jenkins in the
  >   cluster the agents will run on.
- And in section **Configuration on minikube**:

  > - Create and start minikube
  > - The client certificate needs to be converted to PKCS, will need a password
  >
  > ```
  > openssl pkcs12 -export -out ~/.minikube/minikube.pfx -inkey ~/.minikube/apiserver.key -in ~/.minikube/apiserver.crt -certfile ~/.minikube/ca.crt -passout pass:secret
  > ```
  >
  > - Then validate that the certificates work:
  >
  > ```
  > curl --cacert ~/.minikube/ca.crt --cert ~/.minikube/minikube.pfx:secret --cert-type P12 https://$(minikube ip):8443
  > ```
  >
  > - Add a Jenkins credential of type certificate, upload it from `~/.minikube/minikube.pfx`, password `secret`
  > - Fill Kubernetes server certificate key with the contents of `~/.minikube/ca.crt`

If you have any question after that, let me know in the comments or updating your question

Comment: There is no minikube.pfx or apiserver.key in ~/.minikube.